# "Can't use \vadjust in internal vertical mode" triggered by two-line hanging caption, using adjustbox, caption packages

Tags: captions, adjustbox

I want: a floating `table` with caption (with hanging indent), such that both the `table` and caption are surrounded by a frame filled with a background color.

[image]

My environment hierarchy is `table` » `adjust box` » `\caption` » `tabular`.

I'm using the `caption` package to format captions, crucially here with the `format=hang` option.

In the following MWE, the `\caption` command triggers a

`You can't use '\vadjust' in internal vertical mode`

error, but this disappears if any of the following:

- I shorten the caption text so that it doesn't flow to a second line.
- I remove the `format=hang` option from `\captionsetup`

Why does this occur? (I have no idea where `\vadjust` is occurring or why it's throwing an error.)

Or, more generally, an alternative solution that allows both (a) the colored frame surrounding the table and caption and (b) hanging indent for the caption?

I realize that I could dispense with the explicit `table` environment and let the `adjustbox` environment (a) float a table and (b) format the caption. The problem is that my colored frame would then not include the caption (because, per [the `adjust box` docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf), §4.13, keys used to turn an adjusted box into a float "which also allows for a caption… must be used last and no other normal keys must be used again afterwards, otherwise an error will occur because the added floating environment is boxed again").

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=2em, labelfont={bf},format=hang,justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,bgcolor=pink,frame=1pt,center}
        \caption{A caption designed to be long enough that it flows to the next line}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
            Column1 & Column2 \\
            \hline
            $x$ & $y$ \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a minipage?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{margin=2em, labelfont={bf},format=hang,justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{padding=1em,bgcolor=pink,frame=1pt,center}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-1pt-1em}
  \caption{A caption designed to be long enough that it flows to the next line}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
  Column1 & Column2 \\
  \hline
  $x$ & $y$ \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Enrico! Works great. Did you have some idea what was causing the problem in the first place, and that led you to the `minipage` idea?

Comment: @JimRatliff `varwidth` is great, but it doesn't work if paragraphs in it are treated specially, which is the case when the caption is hanging. But as you want essentially all the text width (almost, I mean), a minipage is much easier.